# Can i make a to json from datasource?

Tags: json, extjs

I have a json file:

```
[{
"text": "Company",
"id": "100",
"leaf": false,
"cls": "folder",
"expanded": true,
"children": [{
    "text": "Children Level One 1",
    "id": "02",
    "leaf": false,
    "cls": "folder",
    "expanded": false,
    "children": [{
        "text": "Children Level Two 1",
        "id": "02.02",
        "leaf": false,
        "cls": "folder",
        "children": [{
            "text": "Children Level Three 1",
            "id": "02.02.01",
            "leaf": true,
            "cls": "file"
        }, {
            "text": "Children Level Three 2",
            "id": "02.02.02",
            "leaf": true,
            "cls": "file"
        }]
     }]
    }]
  }]
```

In my ExtJS application i have a three comboboxes. So i want to fill first combo with `"Childrens Level One"`. Next combo with `"Childrens Level Two"` etc. But if i select `"Childrens Level One 1"` in first combo i want that second combo filling with `"Childrens Level Two"` from `"Children Level One 1"`. In my example it is `"Children Level Two 1"`. So can i somehow make a query too my json file?

Comment: Where did you stuck? It's too broad. Try with [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: `Ext.data.TreeStore`?

Comment: TreeStore looks nice, but cant find any examples of using it without Tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach might be to load the JSON data and then load it into separate stores. The "child" store's model could have a "parent" property which stores the id of the parent node. Then, on the `beforequery` event of the dependent combobox you could filter the dependent store by the selected id in the parent combobox. You could pretty easily encapsulate this logic so that you could have N number of nested, related comboboxes.

You could also flatten the json so that all nodes are the same level, just with "parentId" values for nested nodes. Then you use one store, but still be able to filter by selected values.